# Create a client socket with ubuntu sdk

Tags: networking, ubuntu-sdk

A week ago I have installed the Ubuntu SDK. So I'm new and I can't create a client socket that receive a text message from a server, puts the message in a variable and close the connection for my BQ aquaris ubuntu edition because the module Sockets 1.0 isn't implemented in the application.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt doesn't make sockets accessible through QML. It provides only "WebSockets" there.

So, the options are:

- use WebSockets
- get sockets from qml-sockets project and bundle it with your application
- work with sockets only in the C++ part of the application